# Arrow category $\cal K^\to$

Tags: category-theory, morphism, cofibrations

I would like to understand [here](http://www.math.muni.cz/%7Erosicky/papers/brown4.pdf)
on the page $6$ in the definition $3.3$ how works the functor $F:\cal K^\to \to K$.
They say

```
 giving the (cofibration, trivial fibration) factorization
```

By this I understand that we take **one** arrow and factor it into **two** given by this factorization property. But our defined $F$ like that
leads in the opposite direction: we take 2 arrows and assign it 1.

Answer (score 2):

See the beginning of section 2 in the paper. The functor $F$ is meant to send a map to the middle object that appears in its factorisation.

Comment: Could you make more precise the page and line of this `middle object` ? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It is the first paragraph of section two, page 3.